# c# escaping chars trying to run command

Tags: c#, command, escaping, character, line

I'm trying to run this command with several quotation marks:

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --proxy-server="10.10.10.10:9999" -user-data-dir=C:\filterbypass www.example.com"`

I've tried adding backslashes to the before C and after com, no luck

Tried assigning it to a string

`string \"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --proxy-server="10.10.10.10:9999" -user-data-dir=C:\filterbypass www.example.com\"` 
with hopes to run the command like that, but still nothing.

```
try
{
     System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --proxy-server="10.10.10.10:9999" -user-data-dir=C:\filterbypass www.example.com");
}
catch { }
```

Can anyone show me where I'm going wrong here? Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to separate the binary to run from the arguments. I would recommend using `ProcessStartInfo` to make this clearer:

```
var info = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe",
    Arguments = "--proxy-server=10.10.10.10:9999 " +
                @"--user-data-dir=C:\filterbypass " +
                "www.example.com"
};
var process = Process.Start(info);
```

(Note the use of `--` for the `user-data-dir` switch, by the way - it looks like all the command line flags are prefixed with `--`, not `-`. It's possible that it works both ways...)

Comment: OK, I am seeing this now: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string[]' to 'string' Any ideas?

Comment: @EyeSeeSharp: See my edit - sorry, I should have checked the property type first.